# Did Bhishma depart on Astami?

Tags: mahabharata, bhishma

Bhishma astami is celebrated on Magha Shukla Astami as the day he departed. However [Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b132.htm) says:

> O Yudhishthira, the lunar month of Magha has come. This is, again, the lighted fortnight and **a fourth part of it** ought by this (according to my calculations) be over.

> māgho 'yaṃ samanuprāpto māsaḥ puṇyo yudhiṣṭhira
> tribhāgaśeṣaḥ pakṣo 'yaṃ śuklo bhavitum arhati

Why it's Astami when it's said a fourth part of the Paksha which comes to 3-4 days?

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of lunar calendars:

- Purnimanta (month ends on purnima/full-moon day)
- Amanta (month ends on amavasya/no-moon day)

Next Bhishma Ashtami falls on 8th February 2022. If we check calendar for that day in both the calendars then we find these things:

- Purnimanta : https://www.drikpanchang.com/panchang/day-panchang.html?date=08/02/2022 : "23, Magha" -- means it's 23rd day of Magha i.e. three parts over and forth part remaining
- Amanta : https://www.drikpanchang.com/panchang/day-panchang.html?date=08/02/2022 ==> Click on "Switch to Amanta" : "08, Magha" -- means it's 8th day of Magha i.e. fourth part over and three parts remaining

---

"Why it's Astami when it's said a fourth part of the Paksha which comes to 3-4 days?"

You are interpreting it in wrong way, it's fourth part of the month which comes to 7-8 days and not the fourth part of the paksha which comes to 3-4 days. As per Amanta lunar calendar, fourth part of the month gets over on Shukla Paksha Ashtami. The alternate Gitapress translation :

> [image: Gitapress translation]

Comment: Very good explanation! 